# Preciso fazer um relatório que traga a ultima venda de cada produto sendo em SQL

Tags: sql, data

Nesse relatório preciso trazer somente o campo com a ultima saída do produto X com os respective campos codigo, desc, cliente e etc tem fazer dessa forma, porem os campos se repetem

```
SELECT distinct 
nts.not_numero,
nts.not_danfe_numero                                                          AS NF,
--CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), nts.not_dat_emissao, 103)                                AS DATA_NF,
(SELECT TOP 1 CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CAST(MAX(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),nts.not_dat_emissao,112)) AS DATETIME),103)  
FROM tbl_notas nts WHERE pro.pro_codigo = mov.pro_codigo )                    AS DATA_SAIDA,
cli.cli_razao_social                                                          AS RAZAO_SOCIAL,
pro.pro_codigo                                                                AS CODIGO_PRODUTO,
(pro_descricao + ' ' + pro_apresentacao)                                      AS DESCRICAO,
pro.pro_codigo_barras                                                         AS EAN,
pro.pro_prc_venda                                                             AS PRECO_VENDAS,
pro_prc_ult_compra                                                            AS PRECO_ULTIMA_COMPRA,
PRO_PERC_CUSTO_OPERACIONAL, 
(pro_prc_ult_compra * pro_perc_custo_operacional) / 100                       AS VLR_PERC_CUST_OP,
PRO_PERC_ST_ESPECIAL,   
(pro_prc_ult_compra * PRO_PERC_ST_ESPECIAL)/100 AS VLR_ST_ESPECIAL,
pro_per_desc_custo_ven as PERC_DESC_CUST_FARM    
 FROM tbl_produtos pro
 INNER JOIN tbl_moviment_pro mov ON pro.pro_codigo = mov.pro_codigo    ---tbl corpos da nota fisca 
 INNER JOIN tbl_notas nts ON nts.not_numero = mov.mov_numero_nf  ---tbl cabeçario da Nota fiscal 
 INNER JOIN tbl_cliente cli ON cli.cli_codigo = nts.cli_codigo  ---tbl cliente
```

Comment: Se a última venda é a ocorrida na data mais recente então utilize a cláusula GROUP BY produto e a função de agregação MAX(data_da_venda).

Comment: ... where nts.not_dat_emissao = (select max(nts.not_dat_emissao) from tbl_notas nts2 where nts2.cli_codigo = nts.cli_codigo) ... algo assim sem o subselect na seleção